# Von Bertalanffy growth equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the von Bertalanffy growth equation be given by $\frac{dW}{dt}=\alpha W^\lambda-\beta W$ with $W(0)=W_o$ and $\lambda \neq 1$.

Let $y(t)=W^{1-\lambda}$. Show that $\frac{dy}{dt}=(1-\lambda)(\alpha-\beta y)$.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to start this problem.

My original plan was to find $W$ from $\frac{dW}{dt}$, then plugging $W$ into $y(t)=W^{1-\lambda}$, and then differentiating it in order to find  $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

However, I encountered problems using that method because finding $W$ is very messy, but also because finding $\frac{dy}{dt}$ from $y(t)$ is $0$.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: hint:$$\frac{dW}{dt}=\alpha W^\lambda-\beta W =\\ W^\lambda (\alpha -\beta W^{1-\lambda})=\\W^\lambda (\alpha -\beta y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{dW}{dt}=\alpha W^\lambda-\beta W =\\ W^\lambda (\alpha -\beta W^{1-\lambda})=\\W^\lambda (\alpha -\beta y)\tag{1}$$ sonow ,use chain rule
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dW}.\frac{dW}{dt}=\\(1-\lambda)W^{1-\lambda-1}.\frac{dW}{dt}=\\
(1-\lambda)W^{1-\lambda-1}.\frac{dW}{dt}=\\(w.r.t. (1) \to )\\(1-\lambda)W^{1-\lambda-1}.W^\lambda (\alpha -\beta y)=\\
(1-\lambda) (\alpha -\beta y)$$